# Tree Node MySQL to PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need help. I have a tree code in mysqli and I'm trying to translate it into PDO statement. Any advice? Thanks before

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            $node = array();
            $node['id'] = $row['id'];
            $node['text'] = $row['name'];
            $node['state'] = has_child($row['id']) ? 'closed' : 'open';
            array_push($result,$node);
        }

   function has_child($id)
   {
     $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from
     nodes where parentId=$id");
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
     return $row[0] > 0 ? true : false;
   }
```

Create Table SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `parentId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Insert SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `nodes` VALUES 
    ('1', '0', 'Node 1'), 
    ('2', '0', 'Node 2'), 
    ('3', '0', 'Node 3'), 
    ('4', '0', 'Node 4'), 
    ('5', '1', 'Node 1.1'), 
    ('6', '1', 'Node 1.2'),
    ('7', '5', 'Node 1.1.1'), 
    ('8', '5', 'Node 1.1.2'), 
    ('9', '5', 'Node 1.1.3');
```

Comment: you need that block of code transcribed to PDO? most likely you'll change other parts of your code, that also includes the connection

Comment: You aren't using `mysqli` you are using `mysql_*` but the code you've displayed would pretty much be the same in PDO. You still need to fetch and then access the results from the `$row` array.

Comment: You can simply return the value of a logical operation, you don't need a ternary to turn `true` into `true`.

Comment: Hi @chris85  You really a enlighter..  My problems solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array();
try{
$query->execute();  
while($row =$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$node = array();
$node['id'] = $row['id'];
$node['text'] = $row['name'];
$node['state'] = $this->has_child($row['id']) ? 'closed' : 'open';
array_push($result,$node);
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());}
    return json_encode($result);    
}
```

Thank you all....